# Get certain JS file when page response like media queries

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, media-queries

I Need to get certain JS files when page response.

for example:
If the page min-width 800px get this

```
<script" src="800.js"></script>
```

And if page min-width 1920px get this

```
<script" src="1920.js"></script>
```

Just like css media queries but just to get js files.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

have a look at MatchMedia https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js should be exactly what you need

Comment: I have tried using it but I can not find a way to work, Thank You

Comment: look into how to dynamically add/remove scripts using javascript. Then, do that within a couple MatchMedia if statements

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer to this problem is described in the article [Media specific JavaScript](http://javascript.about.com/od/guidesfunctionlibrary/a/Media-Specific-Javascript.htm) written by ***Stephen Chapman***.

There is snippet `isMedia()` writen by ***Nicholas Zakas***. It can be found here [isMedia()](https://gist.github.com/nzakas/08602e7d2ee448be834c)